# Appropriate use of tag wikis

Tags: discussion

I wrote some text for the tag "design" which discusses some basic concepts about the design process.  I was active on another stackexchange site and know that people added general knowledge and resources to the site tags back then (not sure if that has changed).   I started writing to address a badge requirement and chose design since I have experience in it. After writing it I thought it would make a good answer to a question nobody has asked yet and not be appropriate for a tag.  I'm not sure. However, I do think that if the tag is a wiki it might be appropriate to hold some generic knowledge, especially a bibliography and links to resources pertaining to a subject.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding about that information is that it should be about the tag and it's use.  Not about the word/process/item itself.

Now that doesn't mean we can't accept that here if there is enough support for it.

It was an excellent 'answer' and in all honesty you could ask a the question and post that answer to it.  Making sure your question is in scope.

Comment: What about reference links.  When I find a good book or reference on a subject I be happy to share that info as a general resource rather have to search for it from scratch when answering a question.  I think questions asking "Where can I find more info on..." could be answered by pointing the asker to the tag wiki. Does this seem out of scope for a tag?

Comment: I'm not sure.  in general the SE sites don't want answers where the bulk of the answer is sending someone away from the site, however, these would be for reference in a less obvious spot.  I could be convinced, but I think we would need more peoples opinions on this.