# what is a tag wiki and where are they?

Tags: discussion

I think I am missing something.  At 1500 reputation a user qualifies to edit Tag Wikis.  Is this the same as the tag descriptive text found under  'more info' ?

I looked at the description of a tag wiki and found this

> Tag wikis are a general introduction to a topic defined by that tag. They're a place to consolidate and form a sub-community around a tag. They contain, among other things, frequently asked questions in the tag, top users in the tag, and best recent answers in the tag.

I have not seen anything on this site that appears to actively do this.  Earlier I wrote an extension to the tag 'design' which was discussed in meta on this question: ([Appropriate use of tag wikis](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317/appropriate-use-of-tag-wikis)).  At the time I thought I had misinterpreted the intent of tags, but after reading this, I am a bit confused.

Comment: Well, I learn something new everyday.  I don't think I've ever read that.  That makes me think your edit on that tag was legitimate.

Comment: It strikes me that there is an opportunity to enhance the site using this feature

Comment: Yes.  Now that I know that the tag wiki is meant to be used as such, feel free.

Answer (score 1):

The [privilege you are referring to](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) allows you to **approve tag wiki edits**

This would apply to both components of tag wiki's. Tag wikis consist of:

> The **usage guidance**, or **tag wiki excerpt**, is a short blurb that describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically.

I commonly see this referred to as the wiki excerpt. That is what you see as the short description when the tip appears over a tag.

> The **full tag wiki** is a detailed introduction to the topic, suitable as a destination for those curious about it:

That is the full content of the wiki which is meant to provide more in depth information about the tag like what you have quoted in you question.

---

Now that we have a good question base I agree that we should be going into these and making some good tag descriptions.